# Estimate the number of ants in a colony

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A friend of mine gave me this weird problem I cannot solve.

*To estimate the number of ants in a colony an entomologist draws 5500 ants randomly from the colony, labels them with a radioactive isotope and then put them back in. The day after he comes back to the colony and draws 70000 ants randomly. Given that 2 ants show the trace of the isotope, which is the estimated number of ants in the colony? (Assume no ant can die or be born).*

So there are 5500 special balls in an urn of $N$ balls. If I draw 70000 balls, the probability of finding $x$ special balls is (If I am not mistaken)

$P(x)=\dfrac{\binom{5500}{x}\binom{N-5500}{70000-x}}{\binom{N}{70000}}$

should I find the max of this function (how?) and then use $x=2$ to find $N$? Or there are better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run the simple proportion:
$$
2/70000=5500/N
$$
The concentration of marked ants is about the same in big samples. 
So $N=5500*70000/2=192500000$

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice for me.

Comment: 200 million ants would be [one of the largest colonies on earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony).

Comment: I am not who defines the numbers.

Comment: May be in the original problem we have 7000? I hardly can imagine checking 70000 ants.

Comment: Very nice... I thought solving it would imply heavy calculations

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of [Mark-Recapture](http://www.radford.edu/~jkell/mark_rec103.pdf) population estimation. It's accuracy is [debatable](http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/1/12.full) due to the inability to ensure truly random sampling. here's the wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture). You'll notice that the implied variance is astronomical given the large samples and small recapture rate.

Comment: I agree with you, but here is a mathematical riddle, rather than a real problem.

Comment: Thank you for the links, very interesting. +1